# Understanding MongoDB Log warning

Tags: mongodb, aws, centos, mongodb-3.2

In my MongoDB log, I am seeing these lines of messages:

```
2016-04-05T00:03:42.904+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 200, after asserts: 240, after backgroundFlushing: 380, after connections: 510, after dur: 650, after extra_info: 930, after globalLock: 1070, after locks: 1190, after network: 1270, after opcounters: 1310, after opcountersRepl: 1310, after storageEngine: 1430, after tcmalloc: 1620, at end: 2900 }
2016-04-05T00:03:49.910+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 160, after asserts: 220, after backgroundFlushing: 390, after connections: 580, after dur: 670, after extra_info: 890, after globalLock: 1000, after locks: 1180, after network: 1280, after opcounters: 1420, after opcountersRepl: 1610, after storageEngine: 1920, after tcmalloc: 2180, at end: 3360 }
2016-04-05T00:03:57.334+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 140, after asserts: 320, after backgroundFlushing: 470, after connections: 550, after dur: 650, after extra_info: 970, after globalLock: 1190, after locks: 1430, after network: 1480, after opcounters: 1590, after opcountersRepl: 1810, after storageEngine: 2050, after tcmalloc: 2630, at end: 3440 }
2016-04-05T00:04:01.368+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 290, after asserts: 330, after backgroundFlushing: 410, after connections: 440, after dur: 470, after extra_info: 630, after globalLock: 710, after locks: 820, after network: 880, after opcounters: 900, after opcountersRepl: 900, after storageEngine: 940, after tcmalloc: 1040, at end: 1300 }
2016-04-05T00:04:04.404+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 80, after asserts: 130, after backgroundFlushing: 220, after connections: 290, after dur: 370, after extra_info: 490, after globalLock: 570, after locks: 670, after network: 700, after opcounters: 700, after opcountersRepl: 700, after storageEngine: 740, after tcmalloc: 920, at end: 1320 }
2016-04-05T00:04:07.161+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 160, after asserts: 210, after backgroundFlushing: 300, after connections: 390, after dur: 490, after extra_info: 670, after globalLock: 750, after locks: 780, after network: 800, after opcounters: 820, after opcountersRepl: 820, after storageEngine: 860, after tcmalloc: 1000, at end: 1420 }
2016-04-05T00:04:10.229+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 180, after asserts: 240, after backgroundFlushing: 350, after connections: 450, after dur: 530, after extra_info: 630, after globalLock: 740, after locks: 820, after network: 860, after opcounters: 870, after opcountersRepl: 870, after storageEngine: 910, after tcmalloc: 990, at end: 1410 }
2016-04-05T00:04:13.826+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 130, after asserts: 180, after backgroundFlushing: 230, after connections: 280, after dur: 340, after extra_info: 440, after globalLock: 560, after locks: 720, after network: 810, after opcounters: 890, after opcountersRepl: 940, after storageEngine: 1070, after tcmalloc: 1250, at end: 1650 }
2016-04-05T00:04:17.022+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 130, after asserts: 180, after backgroundFlushing: 260, after connections: 300, after dur: 340, after extra_info: 440, after globalLock: 530, after locks: 630, after network: 680, after opcounters: 710, after opcountersRepl: 710, after storageEngine: 730, after tcmalloc: 820, at end: 1100 }
2016-04-05T00:04:20.562+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 140, after asserts: 190, after backgroundFlushing: 270, after connections: 330, after dur: 350, after extra_info: 540, after globalLock: 600, after locks: 660, after network: 720, after opcounters: 760, after opcountersRepl: 820, after storageEngine: 950, after tcmalloc: 1130, at end: 1450 }
2016-04-05T00:04:24.290+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 170, after asserts: 230, after backgroundFlushing: 280, after connections: 360, after dur: 440, after extra_info: 570, after globalLock: 660, after locks: 720, after network: 760, after opcounters: 760, after opcountersRepl: 760, after storageEngine: 840, after tcmalloc: 990, at end: 1260 }
2016-04-05T00:04:28.683+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 70, after asserts: 110, after backgroundFlushing: 160, after connections: 170, after dur: 170, after extra_info: 310, after globalLock: 410, after locks: 560, after network: 650, after opcounters: 750, after opcountersRepl: 800, after storageEngine: 890, after tcmalloc: 1030, at end: 1530 }
```

When I tried to check the status of the MongoDB service, the OS returns this message:

```
mongod dead but subsys locked
```

The logs were caught hours after a query has been ran on the MongoDB so I am eliminating that it was caused by a query (or should I not?). How should I start my trouble-shooting? Would this be an OS issue or a MongoDB usage issue? (New to MongoDB here..)

Comment: Similar discussion at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-28712: "strace the monitor-agent to see if mongod's smaps is being read"